Pandas calculation not working as expected
Hopefully this is a simple fix that I'm overlooking. I am trying to create a calculation for a column, based on the contents of two other columns.  Below is a sample of the data.



Date
Tm
Site
Opp
Result
Player
Dist
Made
Blocked
Year
Month




2024-11-03
PHI
H
JAX
W 28-23
Jake Elliott
57
N
N
2024
11


2024-11-03
MIN
H
IND
W 21-13
Will Reichard
53
N
N
2024
11


2024-11-03
NOR
A
CAR
L 22-23
Blake Grupe
51
Y
N
2024
11


2024-11-03
NWE
A
TEN
L 17-20
Joey Slye
56
N
N
2024
11


2024-11-03
NWE
A
TEN
L 17-20
Joey Slye
52
Y
N
2024
11



What I'm trying to do is to create a column titled "Season", which would be populated by the Year column unless the Month column has a value of 1. If that's the case, then the value should be the year - 1. Here's the code I used:
df["season"] = np.where(df["Month"] == "1",  df["Year"] - 1, df['Year'])

When I run this, the condition doesn't work, and the Season column is only populated with the value from the Year column.
Am I missing something simple?

What's the data type of month? 1=="1" is False

I'm guessing you just accidentally put quotes on "1", so the problem is essentially a typo. But if your confusion actually does go deeper, please [edit] to clarify. And please write a better title while you're there; see [ask] for tips on that.

try updating your condition to compare with the integer 1 instead
df["season"] = np.where(df["Month"] == 1, df["Year"] - 1, df["Year"])


Ugh...thank you for your kindness.

Pandas DataFrames have a dtype attribute that essentially forces a data type on all values in the DF.
From pandas.DataFrame docs

dtype : dtype, default None
Data type to force. Only a single dtype is allowed. If None, infer.

You may want to check that your DataFrame is being created/read in with the dtype attribute explicitely set to str. This will force the DF to cast each value to a String, regardless of what it looks like.
It seems like your program is inferring that the Month is an int type, which is causing the comparison df["Month"] == "1" to fail no matter what (values of type int will never equal values of type str). It could be performing this comparison: int(1) == "1" which will return False. This is why the method is simply sending the Year to the season field, as your code tells it to.
Give it a try and see if this solves anything!

The page you're quoting covers the dtype parameter, not attribute. The relevant attribute is .dtypes (note the S).

Why would you want to force numeric values to strings? Just do df["Month"] == 1 instead.

Nitpick: int(1) is redundant. You can just write 1 since 1 is already an int.

@wjandrea I was just trying to keep as close to OP's code; they may have needed to use strings in some way that wasn't included in the post. Also, the int(1) was simply for clarity, not to actually cast 1 to 1. Additionally, the way I use DFs in my work almost explicitly requires me to convert numbers to strings (to preserve leading/trailing zeros) so that was just my personal experience bleeding in. Thanks for the feedback, regardless.
